# Rails not set cookie on API call from emberjs APP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, cookies, ember.js, ruby-grape

I send a post request to my API located at http://api.board.app.dev:82/api/private/v1/users/current from my emberjs app located at http://www.app.dev:4200/.

The returned data is saved in localestorage but I also want to save token on cookie.

Actually, I do this :

```
  cookies[:user] = 1
  return { status: 'ok', token: user.authentication_token, email: user.email }
```

I see the cookie on the response :

[image]

But when I go to http://api.board.app.dev:82/api/private/v1/users/current I never see the cookie in the chrome console.

Any idea ?

Comment: What CORS headers do you set, or do you proxy the requests to the backend?

Comment: I fixed by setting the token from the JavaScript side.

Comment: You need to set the CORS headers in order for a cookie from `http://api.board.app.dev:82` to be readable from `http://www.app.dev:4200` as one contains a subdomain and they have different ports.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-Domain Cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies)